# How can I start with all the nodes collapsed in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

Starting from this example http://bl.ocks.org/1062288 I would like to have a tree with all the nodes collapsed, so the initial graph should contain only one node (the root).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Option 1: Modify the JSON**

Modify the JSON file, `readme.json`, to use `_children` instead of `children`.

**Option 2: Edit the Javascript**

Edit the javascript to switch the `_children` and `children` attributes for every node. This could be done like so

```
var nodes = flatten(root);
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d._children = d.children;
  d.children = null;
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/Khwnp/) for the second option.

Comment: Brant Do you know a way of navigating all the nodes and set them to open. Your answer showed me that `_children`is closed with `children` being open. I would like to have a single click even to toggle the tree fully open/closed. tia http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/vV3Sc/

Comment: hey @BrantOlsen i have a question. 
I dont want to have all the nodes in one json.
I would rather load just a root first and then when i click i load another json and then somehow create link with its parents.
Can you update me on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: @user414209 You should put that into a new question so all may see it.

Comment: @BrantOlsen I tried option 1 and got some odd results with the source nodes disappearing but option 2 worked out nicely. I updated your fiddle to fix the broken link: http://jsfiddle.net/headwinds/Ge58Q/

Answer (score 2):

```
var allnode =  flatten(root);
for (var i=0;i<allnode.length;i++){click(allnode[i])}
```

for those still looking for it, here is 2 lines of code. compact and easy to understand.

Comment: nice addition - I used it with this awesome sample code base - http://www.is.kau.se/julioangulo/angulo/blog/?p=157568737 -to get the desired effect of starting fully collapsed instead of fully expanded which for me is overwhelming - I'd rather explore the tree and eventually get there.

Answer (score 1):

Put this here for future readers:

```
d3.json("json/results.json", function(json) {
    root = json;
    root.x0 = h / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
      toggle(d);
    }
}

root.children.forEach(toggleAll);

toggle(root);
update(root);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/vV3Sc/