# Tree structure-starting with only root node onload

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree-structure

I am building a tree diagram as in: http://bl.ocks.org/2503502.

I would like to have a tree with all the nodes collapsed, so the initial graph should contain only one node (the root). When the page loads, only the root node should be shown, then when clicked, the rest of the child nodes are shown.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see this was asked a while ago but I'll answer it anyway as I was in a similar situation.

You have a couple of options here depending if you would like the root node clickable and for the child nodes to appear in full (after clicking on root) as it appears currently on the example you provided or if you want all of the child nodes to be collapsed aswell.

**OPTION 1** (only root node collapsed)

On initialisation of the `d3` object where in the function it is coded with `update(root);` (do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for it) put in `toggle(root)`. The variable name `root` is according to the example given, your version and function names may be different (as you have not provided an example code to work off).

**OPTION 2** (all nodes collapsed)

You do the same as Option 1 above but just before the newly inserted `toggle(root);` you also put `root.children.forEach(toggleAll);` where `toggleAll` is a function you will also need to insert which is:

```
function toggleAll(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
        toggle(d);
    }
}
```

**Alternative Options**

The options I have given are not limited to the above. If you follow this example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649427) by brantolsen.github.com you will find other examples of implementing what you are trying to achieve.