# How do I start d3.js tree in a collapsed position?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got the d3.js code to create a tree, which I have happily done, but I can't figure out how to start the tree collapsed.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647653/how-can-i-start-with-all-the-nodes-collapsed-in-d3js) that explains how to do it but it didn't seem to do anything to my code: `Edit the javascript to switch the _children and children attributes for every node. This could be done like so`

```js
var treeData = [


{
    "name": "Product",
        "parent": "null",
        "children": [

    <!-------------- BRANCH -----------> 

    {
        "name": "Servers",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [{
            "name": "Options (Hard disk / RAM / PSU / Network cards etc)",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Software licensing – Microsoft O/S?",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Switching – HP / Cisco",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "UPS – APC",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Cabling",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Warranty – Ecare+ / HP Care Pack?",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Engineer Installation – on-site / remote log-in?",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Config centre – Build & test server and parts prior to delivery",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Telephone support credits",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }

        ]
    },

    <!-------------- BRANCH ----------->    

    {
        "name": "PC/Laptop/Workstation",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [{
            "name": "Monitor",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Docking Station",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Microsoft Office license",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Carry Case (laptop)",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Accessories – Mouse/Keyboard/Riser/Keylock",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Config centre – desktop imaging/adding 2nd HD or RAM",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "On-site installation – desktop rollout",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Telephone Support credits",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }

        ]
    },

    <!-------------- BRANCH ----------->    

    {
        "name": "Switches",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [{
            "name": "SFP/Transceivers",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "Cables",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "Config Centre – pre-delivery config work",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "Network cards",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "On-site installation",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }

        ]
    },






    <!-------------- BRANCH ----------->   



    <!-------------- END -----------> 
    ]
},

];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 250;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}
```

```css
 .node {
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 .node circle {
     fill: #fff;
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 3px;
 }
 .node text {
     font: 12px sans-serif;
     background-color:##
 }
 .link {
     fill: none;
     stroke: #ccc;
     stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[Alternative fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnpv76b5/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that needs to change is `children` to `_children` for the root node.

```js
var treeData = [
{
    "name": "Product",
        "parent": "null",
        "_children": [

    <!-------------- BRANCH -----------> 

    {
        "name": "Servers",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "_children": [{
            "name": "Options (Hard disk / RAM / PSU / Network cards etc)",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Software licensing – Microsoft O/S?",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Switching – HP / Cisco",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "UPS – APC",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Cabling",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Warranty – Ecare+ / HP Care Pack?",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Engineer Installation – on-site / remote log-in?",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Config centre – Build & test server and parts prior to delivery",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }, {
            "name": "Telephone support credits",
                "parent": "Servers"
        }

        ]
    },

    <!-------------- BRANCH ----------->    

    {
        "name": "PC/Laptop/Workstation",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "_children": [{
            "name": "Monitor",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Docking Station",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Microsoft Office license",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Carry Case (laptop)",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Accessories – Mouse/Keyboard/Riser/Keylock",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Config centre – desktop imaging/adding 2nd HD or RAM",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "On-site installation – desktop rollout",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }, {
            "name": "Telephone Support credits",
                "parent": "PC/Laptop/Workstation"
        }

        ]
    },

    <!-------------- BRANCH ----------->    

    {
        "name": "Switches",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "_children": [{
            "name": "SFP/Transceivers",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "Cables",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "Config Centre – pre-delivery config work",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "Network cards",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }, {
            "name": "On-site installation",
                "parent": "Switches"
        }

        ]
    },
    <!-------------- BRANCH ----------->   

    <!-------------- END -----------> 
    ]
},
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
},
width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 250;
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}
```

```css
 .node {
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 .node circle {
     fill: #fff;
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 3px;
 }
 .node text {
     font: 12px sans-serif;
     background-color:##
 }
 .link {
     fill: none;
     stroke: #ccc;
     stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you may need to full screen the snipper to see its results.

Comment: Thanks, got it now! I was changing all the `children` to `_children`. This does do what I was after but I have no realised after clicking the first node it open _everything_ up. Is there a way to have it all collapsed and gradually open as I click each node?

Comment: Change every `children` to `_children`. This will make them all collapsed.

Comment: every single one in the js? I'm sure I tried this before and nothing loaded

Comment: Oh brilliant! I see what you mean now :) thanks for that, I'll know for the future